# Javascript to insert "/" in output numbers to format the date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have simple unformatted date output of 8 digits like this:

```
<div class="date">20170822</div>
```

And looking for a simple js/jquery script to insert "/" after 4th and 6th digit to make it:

```
<div class="date">2017/08/22</div>
```

Thanks, any help appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: you should show the code you tried to let us know you at least attempted to research. What you can do here is use substrings.

Comment: Have you tried using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like 
`"20170822".replace(/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");`

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".date");
els.forEach(function(el){
  var d = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML= d.replace(/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
  
});
```

```html
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170102</div>
<div class="date">20170408</div>
<div class="date">20170310</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely but only on the first div, I have 8 of them, could you add support for serveral divs on same page?

Comment: Yes! the example is edited now, the querySelector take the first node, use querySelectorAll:   https://codepen.io/cbertelegni/pen/EwgGKb?editors=1111
```var els = document.querySelectorAll(".date");
els.forEach(function(el){
  var d = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML= d.replace(/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
  
});
```

Comment: @Lawyer See my updated answer for a way to handle all the dates.

Comment: Please don't post working code to 3rd party sites. Those links can become dead over time. Just insert a "code snippet" into your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple js to do so

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".date").each(function(i,elem) {
    var divdate = $(this).html();
    var lenght = divdate.length;
    var newdate = '';
    
    for(var i = 0;i<lenght;i++){
       if(i==3){
       
        newdate +=  divdate[i] +'/';
       }
       else
       if(i==5){
          newdate +=  divdate[i] +'/';
       }
       else{
       newdate += divdate[i];
     }
    }
    $(this).html(newdate);});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20191229</div>
<div class="date">20161025</div>
<div class="date">20150620</div>
```

Comment: Works very well for the slashes, thank you. Could you please make it support several divs at the same time? I have 8 different dates on the same page and it gives me exactly same output/date for all of them now

Comment: @Lawyer done, see the code, for all div with `class `of `.date`

Comment: This is really a convoluted answer. Way too involved with way too much processing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what the convoluted in a for loop ^^', this is basic programming

Comment: The nested loop. The nested `if/else`. The JQuery. `.html()` instead of `.text()`. The manual construction of a new string instead of simple insertion.

Comment: Is adding unnecessary nested loops with unnecessary nested if/else logic that parses text unnecessarily for HTML that doesn't exist by downloading a library that isn't needed to use wrappers around fundamental JavaScript, "basic programming"? Well, the individual pieces may be "basic", but what you've assembled sure isn't. That's a hot-mess.

Answer (score -1):

The `/` characters need to be inserted into the set of characters. JavaScript Arrays have a **[`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method for doing just this kind of thing, but strings are not true arrays, they are "array-like" objects. However, they can be converted to true arrays very easily.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**:

> **Array-like objects**
>
> `slice` method can also be called to convert Array-like objects /
>   collections to a new Array. You just bind the method to the object.
>   The arguments inside a function is an example of an 'array-like
>   object'.

Once that is done, the **[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method will solve the problem.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".date");  // Get all the divs into a node-list (array-like object)

// Convert the node list to an array (so Array.forEach can be used) and loop over the array
[].slice.call(divs).forEach(function(d){
  var sAry = [].slice.call(d.textContent); // Convert the text content of the div to an array

  // Insert the / at the index positions
  sAry.splice(4,0,"/");
  sAry.splice(7, 0, "/");

  d.textContent = sAry.join("");  // Update the div with the formatted value
});
```

```html
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
<div class="date">20170822</div>
```

Comment: why everybody looks for complex solutions: simple `d.innerText.split('')` is way more readable than `[].slice.call(d.textContent)`. Transforming string to array and back is also not the best piece of code when simple `substr()` three times in one line is also sufficient

Comment: @smnbbrv Because Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. Answers should educate as well as answer the question. My code is written the way it is to explicitly draw attention to the fact that the string needs conversion.

Comment: so now every developer would write those operators instead of simple `substr` with `+` and call himself a cool guy

Comment: @smnbbrv Try this (where `nl` is a node-list): `var newArray = nl.split('');`. Your comment implies that you can always get an array with `.split()`, when you can't. My code is more robust. Also, `innerText` will not get descendant content, `textContent` will.

Comment: Really, a down vote for a working answer that is well explained. Come on Stack Overflow. Check your egos at the door.